# If a "private static int" instance variable is not initialized, does it equal to zero?

Tags: java

If a "private static int" instance variable is not initialized, does it equal to zero?

For example:

```
private static int number;
```

Is number equal to zero?

Comment: yes - 0 is the default value.

Comment: Why don't you try it? And YES.

Comment: @Eran this doesn't apply to non-static variables too, right?

Comment: @user10610048 it applies to both static and instance variables. It doesn't apply to local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since the default value for int will be `0`

Comment: Does this apply to non-static instance variables too?

Comment: It applies to instance variables as well

Comment: Just to make it clear it's not `"0"` but `0`

Comment: Yes. Didn't mean it as a String. Just wanted to highlight it. Thanks @PeterLawrey

Comment: use ` and ` to highlight as code.

Comment: c.f. the default for `char` is `'\0'`